# PHP / OOP Performance - Methods vs. Array

Tags: php, performance, oop

Using Zend Framework or any other framework alike on a large project (around 2 milion users per day) where efficiency is a major problem, I would like to know which of the following methods is more optim from performance point of view whenever you need to access, for example, data of **$_POST** Global Variable.

Is better calling multiple chainable methods or call them once, save into a variable and then just specifying required key ?

## Method 1

```
echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('key1') . 
$this->getRequest()->getParam('key2');
```

## Method 2

```
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
echo $post['key1] . $post['key2'];
```

Saying that for multiple keys, like at least 5 or more.

Comment: Just check it. Test & get the result. It's the only way.

Comment: Why not test it yourself?

Comment: i guess it's faster calling them directly, 'cause you don't initializate any variable and just access to the property directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Speed != Speed

It's a hard question to answer because these things you will have to test because this depends a lot on the hardware.

Some companies tend to have 'let's add ram' policy where others go for 'let's add CPUs'.

### Your example explained

```
echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('key1') . 
$this->getRequest()->getParam('key2');
```

The speed here depends purely on the complexity of your getRequest() method. Is it a simple return; statement? Nor problem then, let the compilers handle that for you.

Are you performing some logic (e.g an if-else statement)? you should probably 'cache' the result in a variable.

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
```

this will not consume extra memory because $request is internally just a pointer to the Request object.

Your second method:

```
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
echo $post['key1] . $post['key2'];
```

Is bad. Array's (in contrary to objects) are copied on return;

$post is now a copy of the data you had in the request object. Thus using extra ram. selecting the items will ofcourse be faster then calling a method were the items are selected. But it uses more ram. and the bigger $post is, the more ram will be used.

## Again, speed != speed

Is it however a small array? Is your app slow? You won't slove the speed issue by doing small refractoring like this. Make it easy to read! pick one ;)

### side note

I do however see some smelly code. You are in an object (you are using $this). And you are getting another object using the getRequest() method. What are you doing in that method? creating an object? Looks like some tight coupling.

Maybe you should retriee a Request object in your constructor and then simply:

```
$this->request->getParam($ket);
```

Faster, better easier to read and IoC. But then again, this is just an assumption ;) hard to say without getting more context ont Request and amount of params